# Reusing Price Sets and changing their values

Tags: civievent, price-sets, repeating-events, percentage-price-field

We have events running regularly.  Each year the prices change but often the price set structure is the same.  If I change the amount of a price field - e.g. Member ticket £10 last year and go to the same price field and change to £12 this year Will this in any way affect previously logged event contributions or event ticket prices as they have already been logged?

We use sagepay payment processor and take online payments.

Just wanting to not create a new price set every time I run the same event if it's just for a price change.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not change contribution records, but will change any of the forms if they get reloaded. So, if you are not needing to change those past transactions, then you don't have anything to worry about.
I have confirmed it, but you can ease your mind by doing a quick test to confirm for yourself. Find a transaction that uses the price set. Make the price set change and then view the transaction again. No change.

Comment: Excellent - thank you.  I'll check this out in a test.  Does it change what's shown in event registrations that are logged against a user?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by this, but again you can easily test by making a small change and then looking back at older records.